# Transposing ranges separated by blanks rows

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to tinker with this source code that transposes 1 column separated by spaces.

```
Sub Transpose()

Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, iStart As Long, iEnd As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    iStart = 1
    For i = 1 To lastrow + 1
        If .Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then
            iEnd = i
            j = j + 1
            .Range(.Cells(iStart, 1), .Cells(iEnd, 1)).Copy
            ws.Range("A" & j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
            iStart = iEnd + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I'm trying to take take 4 columns ranges with variable rows

[[image: See Here]

And transpose each range adjacently so that it looks like this:

[image]

Any input appreciated.

Comment: Will the transposed data always fit (eg what if there were only two rows for example).  Are you pasting the transposed data next to the source, or just continuously down the sheet with no gaps?

Comment: Now I'm nervous....

Comment: lol given your track history, not sure why you would ^_^ Edit: translation, I am failing at architecting this XD

Comment: @TimWilliams

Good point, it's not always going to fit. 

So I guess rather than placing adjacently, it will have to start pasting in F1 and continue down the sheet with a gap between each different transposition.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub Transpose()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, cCopy As Range, cPaste As Range
    
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Set cCopy = ws.Range("A1")   'top-left of first data block
    Set cPaste = ws.Range("F1")  'first output cell
    
    Do While Len(cCopy.Value) > 0  'while have data to transpose
        
        With cCopy.CurrentRegion
            Debug.Print "Copying", .Address, " to ", cPaste.Address
            cPaste.Resize(.Columns.Count, .Rows.Count) = _
                          Application.Transpose(.Value)
            Set cPaste = cPaste.Offset(.Columns.Count + 1) 'next paste position
            Set cCopy = cCopy.Offset(.Rows.Count + 1)      'next data block
        End With
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub SubRollData()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngSource As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim DblRowOffset As Double
    Dim DblColumnOffset As Double
    
    'Settings.
    Set RngSource = Range("A1")
    Set RngTarget = Range("F1")
    
    'Checkpoint for the block processing.
CP_Block:
    
    'Covering each column.
    For DblColumnOffset = 0 To 3
        
        'Setting DblRowOffset to start covering for the first row of the block.
        DblRowOffset = 0
        
        'Covering each row of the block of the given column until an empty cell is fount.
        Do Until RngSource.Offset(DblRowOffset, DblColumnOffset) = ""
            
            'Reporting the data with switched offset.
            RngTarget.Offset(DblColumnOffset, DblRowOffset).Value = RngSource.Offset(DblRowOffset, DblColumnOffset).Value
            
            'Setting DblRowOffset for the next row.
            DblRowOffset = DblRowOffset + 1
            
        Loop
    Next
    
    'Setting RngSource to aim at the next block.
    If RngSource.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
        Set RngSource = RngSource.Offset(2, 0)
    Else
        Set RngSource = RngSource.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0)
    End If
    
    'Setting RngSource to aim at the next empty row to fill in with data.
    If RngTarget.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
        Set RngTarget = RngTarget.Offset(1, 0)
    Else
        Set RngTarget = RngTarget.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    
    'If RngSource has no data, there is no more block to be processed. Otherwise, the next block is processed.
    If RngSource.Value <> "" Then GoTo CP_Block
    
End Sub
```

It works with the example you've given and also with isoletd (single row) source data.

---

Just for fun, here is a possible formula based solution to be placed in cell F1 and dragged:

```
=IF(COLUMN(F1)-COLUMN($F1)+1>=AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($A:$A="")*ROW($A:$A),QUOTIENT(ROW(F1)-ROW(F$1),4)+1)-IF(QUOTIENT(ROW(F1)-ROW(F$1),4)=0,0,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($A:$A="")*ROW($A:$A),QUOTIENT(ROW(F1)-ROW(F$1),4))),"",INDEX($A:$D,COLUMN(F1)-COLUMN($F1)+1+IF(QUOTIENT(ROW(F1)-ROW(F$1),4)=0,0,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($A:$A="")*ROW($A:$A),QUOTIENT(ROW(F1)-ROW(F$1),4))),MOD(ROW(F1)-ROW(F$1),4)+1))
```

Naturally it's really heavy and stupidly complicated, but as i said: made it just for fun.

Answer (score 0):

Took way too long to do this and the most atrocious architecture but it works.

```
r = 1
c = 1
cl = 6
rw = 1

For r = 1 To 13
    For c = 1 To 4
        If Cells(r, c) <> "" Then
            Cells(rw, cl) = Cells(r, c)
            rw = rw + 1
        End If
    Next
    'If Cells(r, c) = "" Then cl = 6
    rw = 1
    cl = cl + 1

Next

rw = 5
cl = 6

For r = 1 To 4
    For c = 10 To 12
        Cells(rw, cl) = Cells(r, c)
        cl = cl + 1
    Next
        rw = rw + 1
        cl = 6
Next

rw = 9
cl = 6

For r = 1 To 4
    For c = 14 To 18
        Cells(rw, cl) = Cells(r, c)
        cl = cl + 1
    Next
        rw = rw + 1
        cl = 6
Next

Range("J1:R4").ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0):

### Transpose Groups of Data to a New Worksheet

```vb
Sub TransposeGroups()
    
    ' Source - use as-is (read (copy) from)
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirstRowAddress As String = "A1:D1"
    Const sMandatoryColumnIndex As Long = 1 ' dictates if empty row (gap)
    ' Destination - delete if exists and put last (write (paste) to)
    Const dName As String = "Result"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Write the values from the source range to a 2D one-based array
    ' and write its upper limits to variables.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Dim sData As Variant
    Dim srCount As Long
    Dim scCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(sFirstRowAddress)
        Dim lCell As Range
        With .Columns(sMandatoryColumnIndex)
            Set lCell = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
                .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        End With
        If lCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No data in column " & sMandatoryColumnIndex & ".", _
                vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        scCount = .Columns.Count
        srCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
        sData = .Resize(srCount).Value
    End With
        
    ' Loop through the rows of the source array and map the first row,
    ' the last row and the following gap count (empty rows) in each row
    ' of three columns of another 2D one-based array.
    ' Note that this array has the same number of rows as the source array,
    ' but the data of interest will be in much fewer rows ('mr').
    ' (Probably a collection of collections (or three element arrays)
    ' would have been a better choice.)
    
    Dim mArr() As Long: ReDim mArr(1 To srCount, 1 To 3)
        
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim sValueFound As Boolean
    Dim mr As Long
    Dim ccCount As Long
    Dim dcCount As Long
    Dim GapCount As Long
     
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        If Len(CStr(sData(sr, sMandatoryColumnIndex))) > 0 Then
            If Not sValueFound Then
                mr = mr + 1
                mArr(mr, 1) = sr ' first row
                sValueFound = True
            End If
        Else
            If sValueFound Then
                sValueFound = False
                mArr(mr, 2) = sr - 1 ' last row
                ccCount = sr - mArr(mr, 1)
                If ccCount > dcCount Then dcCount = ccCount
            End If
            mArr(mr, 3) = mArr(mr, 3) + 1 ' gap
            GapCount = GapCount + 1 ' to determine the number of rows of 'dData'
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' The very last row (of interest).
    mArr(mr, 2) = srCount
    ccCount = sr - mArr(mr, 1)
    If ccCount > dcCount Then dcCount = ccCount
                
    ' Using the source array and the information from the mapping array,
    ' write the results to the destination array.
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = mr * scCount + GapCount
    
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    Dim drFirst As Long
    
    Dim sc As Long
    Dim dc As Long
    
    For mr = 1 To mr
        For sc = 1 To scCount
            For sr = mArr(mr, 1) To mArr(mr, 2)
                dc = dc + 1
                dData(drFirst + sc, dc) = sData(sr, sc)
            Next sr
            dc = 0
        Next sc
        drFirst = drFirst + sc + mArr(mr, 3) - 1
    Next mr
                
    ' Write the values from the destination array to a new worksheet.
                
    ' Check if a sheet with the same name exists.
    Dim dsh As Object
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dsh = wb.Sheets(dName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' If it exists, delete it without confirmation.
    If Not dsh Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        dsh.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
    ' Add a new worksheet and rename it accordingly.
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    dws.Name = dName
    
    ' Write the values from the destination array to the destination worksheet.
    With dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
        .Resize(drCount, dcCount).Value = dData
    End With
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Groups transposed.", vbInformation
                
End Sub
```